# Javascript Scope Chain Understanding

Tags: javascript, function, closures, scope

I'm reading about Scope Chaining at the moment and wanted to paraphrase my understanding of the concept in order to determine whether or not I am understanding it correctly.

My understanding is this:

1. When a new function is initialized an object for this function is created automatically
2. This object has properties which define the variables to be used within that function
3. This object is added to the chain of objects already created
4. If I had a few nested functions, each of those functions will represent a hierarchical  object in the scope chain. The deeper the nested function, the further down the chain its relative object lives. (The object which defines its variables).

So, in practice, if function one contained function two and function two contained function 3, and function 3 tried to access a variable - the interpreter would move up the scope chain (starting with its own local scope) to try to find this variable and would do so right up to the uppermost function, stopping the first time it is found?

It'd be great if you could give me insight as to whether or not i'm totally barking up the wrong tree here or whether or not i'm generally on the right track?

Thanks,
Jordan

Comment: Have you tried coding it up and seeing if your intuition is correct?

Comment: I have, but, the difficulty is that output alone does not necessarily give you the causal description of how it is occurring.

Comment: Than can you include your code sample, what your outputs were, and what you are confused about? Your intuition definitely seems to be on the right track.

Comment: Your understanding, although not described using the "preferred" terminology, is correct. The only issue I can find is at (1): a function is an object. In fact, except scalar types, everything in JavaScript is an object. `var x = function(a, b, c) { }; x.foo = 'bar';` is in fact correct. `var x = [1, 2, 3]; x.foo = 'bar';` is also correct.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers guys. (No pun intended). My code is as follows here: http://jsfiddle.net/VnZ4U/1/. Purple is returned because the lowest function in the scope chain tries to return a variable which is not local to itself and so it moves up to the most recently declared version of that function name (which happens to belong to the nested function. Perhaps not the best way of demonstrating it - but it seems to make sense in my mind! :)

Comment: Just make sure you never ever do that in real life :) I mean multiple declarations of same variable (except maybe the i in a for loop) and code after a return, when it's not in a control structure (if, while, etc.)